# How do I edit text on graphics downloaded from Shutterstock in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have an event coming up for a social group of mine and have signed up to Shutterstock to download a single flyer (for a not so small fee of $300). All I want to do is use one of the flyers from the website and edit the text for our event. I haven't used Illustrator before, which is why I thought I would simply purchase a graphic that is already made so I can just change some text - which I thought would be a fairly straightforward task.

However from what I have read since, once a text has been converted to an 'outline' there is no way for one to then edit the text, and I must just delete the existing text and replace it with my own. The problem is, I downloaded this particular flyer BECAUSE of the different effects they applied to the text. If I delete their text and insert my own, I am basically left with a blank canvas.

Now as an engineer who works with software everyday, this just seems completely nuts. Surely people don't pay for graphics only to have to then recreate them themselves because Illustrator or whoever made the graphic doesn't include a way to edit text.

Am I missing something here or is this just how it is? Is there some way I can edit the text in the document while keeping the effects applied to it?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots with the layers and appearance panels visible? It's perfectly possible to recreate the text and retain any effects, but it depends how these effects are set up.

Comment: To have the text editable instead of outlines the font would need to be bundled together with the image; unless the creator used some super common font like Arial or Times.

Comment: Shutter stock basically states that fonts need to be outlined. In some stick images the your expected to use the elements and add your own text in others not so. Care to tell what image asset is in question. It its aren't text then no theres nothing you can do,

Comment: Example, if you bought something like [this](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-327787325/stock-vector-merry-christmas-holiday-vector-illustration-lettering-composition-with-light-rays.html?src=TcvVldn147Jc4mf6402I2g-1-36) then no you have no expectations of changing text. if you bought something like [this](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-129229757/stock-vector-modern-spiral-infographics-options-banner-vector-illustration-can-be-used-for-workflow-layout.html?src=YQzQox6kZX6AkWO6axUQcg-1-21) then your expected to supply your won fonts and knowlege to fix same style for new text

Answer (score 2):

Text is not editable on shutterstock items, you just bought a design not a template.

You would be better looking at templates from www.graphicriver.net or creativemarket.com, these are editable. Usually you can find files that can be edited in Photoshop, if you don't know how to use illustrator.

Comment: There are plenty of vector images on shutterstock with editable text.

Comment: In 3 years of having an account with them I haven't found one vector file with open text format, all are outlined - I must be unlucky.

Comment: Fair enough. [Lots](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-56074165/stock-vector-image-of-a-pie-chart-with-editable-text.html) [of](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-102441448/stock-vector-image-of-a-computer-screen-with-editable-text-isolated-on-a-white-background.html) [examples](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-43781458/stock-vector-musical-template-with-piano-keys-notes-and-editable-text-fields.html) though.

Comment: I would assume at least some of the text on a [flyer template](http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=flyer%20template&media_type=images) would be editable, they would be pretty useless otherwise.

Comment: Generally the files are easy to edit but text is outlined so you have to replace with live text and match fonts as needed.

Comment: What the responder said - just downloaded an EPS graphic and text is not editable - and it matters because there's a lot of effects on some text. Shutterstock needs to compel graphics submitters to use photoshop layers or similar - EPS is a vector printing format